# Sum of frequency of values of a coordinate in a cluster

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

Is there a way to show the sum of the sum of count of each coordinate instead of count of the occurrence of that combination

```
city    state   latitude    longitude   Count

        San Juan    PR  18.410462   -66.060533  5
        Honolulu    HI  21.2782 -157.82199  8
        Boca Raton  FL  26.391346   -80.21824   17
        Honolulu    HI  21.2782 -157.82199  7
        Key Biscayne    FL  25.700966   -80.16195   2
```

The code that I use to get the cluster by occurrences is

```
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
)
```

I was able to find come help but on this but the response code in JS and I'm not experiences in JS

I want my output plot to be as in the link below

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html

Comment: At first, learn the difference between js and java...

Comment: The link to the help is

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers